# Why aren't spam questions and answers being deleted?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14491/any-uk-residents-understand-without-asking-them-for-i-d-of-any-tat-areas-in-gla) and [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14496/would-be-clans-conflict-sites-who-declare-to-possess-secrets-for-jewels-actual) are clearly spam and have been voted for Closure and answers tagged as spam.

Why are these questions not being deleted from the site? Do we need additional moderators? I would be happy to help if given the level of authority.

These are making a mess of the site and a mockery of the self-moderation principles in my opinion.

Comment: Hi Marv, thanks for highlighting these spam posts. They've been deleted. We try our best to get to everything as quickly as possible. If you find something that needs more immediate attention feel free to tweet to me @markphillipspm

Comment: Thanks. I don't use Twitter I'm afraid.

Comment: @MarkPhillips another one has appeared...

Comment: Thanks Marv, it has been deleted.

Comment: @MarkPhillips and there's more, e.g. http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/how-do-i-get-clash-of-clans-for-my-chromebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, I usually delete stuff like this on site, because it's blatant, obvious spam, and that's exactly what moderators should do when they come across spam/offensive flags with such content. There's no need to wait for voting mechanisms in these cases, and moderators should feel empowered to remove such content unilaterally. I've been a bit busier than usual lately, as I am out of the United States and am staying in India, so I haven't checked in as much lately.

As I am settling in, I am making it a point to check in everyday again. It's reasonable to expect content like this to be deleted within 24 hours; however, as we are volunteers and not paid staff, sometimes it may take longer, as in this case.

Some sites make use of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-pmse-notice-board) to try and pass information to other high rep users with delete privileges.  That's been extremely helpful on sites like [Workplace SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com), where there is quite a bit of activity.

Keep in mind also that six spam/offensive flags on content like this will cause it to be deleted automatically, so we can also attack this problem by utilizing the review queues more often and understanding that any user with at least 15 reputation can contribute to this process and flag such content.  Hope this helps.

Comment: There are couple more of these, over 24 hours old, see here: http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/how-do-i-get-clash-of-clans-for-my-chromebook - I don't think enough people have got the message about flagging as Spam causing auto deletion. The problem with these (seemingly increasing) spam questions is that they give a bad image to casual visitors. We need to get rid of them as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for highlighting these questions!

From my point of view, you *are already* moderating PMSE, and that's exactly how things should work - most seasoned members helping the community by keeping it organized and objective.

Besides, I believe you'll [eventually have moderator grants](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Our masters mr. Spina and CG (the one from the [law](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/9821/430)) might be able to confirm this.

**Edit:** Oftentimes, I see questions I'd vote to close / delete myself, but happens that doing this would directly execute the voted option, which would go against the idea of having a self moderated community - and I noticed that unless it's a clear case of a question to be closed or deleted, other mods follow this approach too.

So, my view it's a matter of giving room to PMSE to naturally growth (to the point it'd be self managed only by users, not mods).