# Chat room for flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging, spam

Yesterday found another a [SPAM answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/17940/27189), flagged accordingly but the answer still remains there. [This isn't something new in this community](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703/27189) and it's understandable if we consider there's people behind it reviewing, things take time.

[jmort253 's accepted answer](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/707/27189) mentions a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-pmse-notice-board) where one could go to pass that information to users that can take the promised measures that's...

> ... been extremely
>   helpful on sites like Workplace SE, where there is quite a bit of
>   activity.

Once navigating to it, we can see the chat room is frozen and, therefore, new messages cannot be added.

[image: Frozen chat room]

*We are people and we can learn from experience.*

Even though the same SPAM situation already happened, my experience tells it doesn't seem to happen often. Still, i reckon it does happen regularly if, instead of considering only SPAM, we look at flags in general.

Considering what was mentioned, shall we unfroze that chat ([which will require a moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70201/364217)) or create a new one specific to treat flags?

Comment: If you wish, you can report spam in this chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq users from across the network will come to review it.

Comment: That spam answer is from 2016, right?

Comment: Climate change arrived, unfreezing the room. Nevertheless, I tried several times to discuss about specific "not so good" questions by chat and failed miserably. Hope it changes!

Comment: Yes @TiagoCardoso the answer is from 2016.

Comment: I was also wondering it... Specially because opening the chat is not like going to the Review Queus or to Top Questions. To me is still not intuitive to go there.

Comment: There's also another room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19597/project-management) that has a bit more of activity than the other room mentioned. Still, far from common chat rooms we see in other SE communities.